# Slow Redshift COPY Performance into an Interleaved table

Tags: redshift

We are seeing slow performance when using the `COPY` command into an interleaved table with 4 Sort Keys. When I remove the interleaved option, the copy finishes very quickly.

#### These are the stats to copy data from S3 to Redshift:

We loaded 70 million records

Interleaved sort key - 52 mins
Compound sort key - 8 mins
No Sort Key - 7mins

Our sort key had 4 columns in it. We have a `DIST KEY` also.

Can anyone provide a reasoning of why copy performance into an interleaved sort key performs poorly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an automated backup which was running at the same time, which caused the COPY into the Interleaved table go slow..